# Excel vba 1004 method of range class failed: Autofill to varying length column

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to piece this together by referencing other threads here. I think I've mimicked properly but I can't get it to work. Issue pops on my autofill.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("AN" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AO2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(RC[-29])"
Range("AO2").AutoFill Destination:=("AO2:AO" & lastRow)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy;@"
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `AutoFill`. Write the formula to the entire range in one line:

```vb
Range("AO2:AO" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(RC[-29])"
```

The problem with your `AutoFill` attempt is that the *Destination* parameter should be a `Range`, not a `String`: `Destination:=Range("AO2:AO" & lastRow)`